# mysql bulk upload - use generated primary key value in another table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to bulk upload into MySQL database from a text file.
First I am loading all data from the file to a temp helper table (temp_rules_upload) which I would delete after bulk uploads.
Then I want every record from temp table to be inserted into 2 separate tables (table_a & table_b) for the few selected columns.

**Problem:-**

- It first inserts all data in table_a and then inserts all data in table_b.
- How can I control such that after every record inserted into table_a, I want to insert into table_b, as I need to use the primary key of table_a in table_b for every record.
- For every record, I also need to find the primary key for the starting_material_code from another table and set that in table_b.
- Not sure if LOAD DATA is suitable for this requirement. I have millions of data to load other options like JPA are very time consuming

I tried the below script. As it happens in sequence, I only get the last primary key for LAST_INSERT_ID()

**SQL Script:-**

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'rule_1.txt' 
INTO TABLE temp_rules_upload 
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY '|' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES
(groupname,starting_material_code,lower_limit,higher_limit,description,severity,active,created_date,created_by);

insert into table_a(active,create_date,code,description,severity) 
select true,CURDATE(),groupname,description,severity from temp_rules_upload;

SET @ERROR_ID=LAST_INSERT_ID();

insert into table_b(active,create_date,code,description,groupname,higher_limit,lower_limit,compatibility_error_id,starting_material_id) 
select true,CURDATE(),starting_material_code,description,groupname,higher_limit,lower_limit,@ERROR_ID,null from temp_rules_upload;
```

**File Data: (rule_1.txt)**

```
1004 : 1964|1004|||not compatible with zzz|Error|Yes|6/20/2019|AAA
1004 : 1964|1964|||not compatible with ffff|Error|Yes|6/20/2019|AAA
```

Comment: Thanks, temp table is a dummy helper table to load data in table_a and table_b.

Comment: Thanks mate that hack won't solve all problem. As I also have other similar tasks where I need to find the primary key for starting_material_code and set that in table_b

Comment: If you want the primary key from a to be the primary key in b ask yourself whether these two tables should actually be just one. If you still want it then you'll have to join your temp data to a so you can have the columns you want from temp in b plus the pk from a.. or give the data a suitable pk in temp and do the two inserts with the pk you already have

Comment: Thanks. No, both table A & B primary is not the same. Table A primary key would be stored in Table B column 'compatibility_error_id' (foreign key). Is it possible to do with LOAD DATA scripts, or should I write a procedure with cursor to itereate the temporary table and insert into the 2 tables (A&B)

Comment: I note that most (all but one) of your table data in a is also in b - what purpose did a have? Why not load all the data into b? You could have a view that replicates A

Comment: Thanks, there is actually one-to-many relation between Table A and Table B. (Same record in table A could be used in many records in table B)

Comment: Why then would B store al lthe same columns as A? table A is holding: **true,CURDATE(),starting_material_code,description**,severity, and B is holding **true,CURDATE(),starting_material_code,description**,groupname,higher_limit,lower_limit ...

Answer (score 0):

I handled this by splitting into two separate tasks. As I think it is not possible to do all using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`

## 1. Load into a temporary table

- Uploaded the data from a text file into a temporary table with table structure same like the file. This was very fast, it took less than 10 mins to load all the 5+ million data.

## 2. Use stored procs, to load data from temp into actual tables.

- Then used a stored procedure to iterate over all the 5+ million records with the help of a cursor and insert into my 2 tables A & B. However as this involves some logic in the stored procedure it takes 10 hours to upload all the 5+ million data.

My code: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/223424/stored-procs-fine-tuning-for-processing-bulk-data-5-million-records